# Select Point From Which to Preview a Flash File

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I am working a video in Flash CS5 that is roughly 11 minutes long.

I am at the 6 minute mark at the moment and whenever I want to preview the latest changes I click F12 to I press 'alt+enter'. The problem is I have to watch 6 minutes of the SWF to eventually get to the latest part I edited.

This is slowing me down tremendously and I would hate to still be doing this when I am 10 minutes into the video!!!!

Is there a more efficient way to preview?

Perhaps open it in a player that has some proper controls? or even if I could select the starting point of the preview?

If I press 'enter' I see a preview but the sound file does not play so that option is out too.

Comment: I understand from your question that this is a FLV video playing on you timeline, or you are using the default playback component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing in the timeline, right? Add the actionscript `gotoAndPlay(164);’ in the first frame where 164 is the frame you want to skip to. You can also add a function that makes you do this runtime.

Comment: I am new to flash but I started messing with actionscripts after reading your response and it worked..... not to mention there are a lot of other awesome things I can do now... THANKS!!